# Make a Cell Flashing in Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Script File; It will look for two different values in two different columns on the 'table' sheet.
Value in column B: [ELECTRIC]
Value in column D: [CONTINUE]

If it finds even a single row containing the above values;
I want cell [H22] in 'table2' sheet to flash.

How can i get it?

This is the script I've had so far;

```js
function onOpen(){
  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mysheet1 = ss1.getSheetByName("Table");
  var values = mysheet1.getRange(2,2,mysheet1.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var values2 = mysheet1.getRange(2,4,mysheet1.getLastRow()).getValues();

  
  if (values == "ELECTRIC" && values2 == "CONTINUE"){
    var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var mysheet2 = ss2.getSheetByName("Table2");
    var cell = mysheet2.getRange("H22");
      for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      cell.setBackground(i % 2 ? "WHITE" : "RED");
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      Utilities.sleep(500);
    }
  }  
}
```

Thank you for your help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) returns a 2-dimensional array, not a string. You will need to loop through the values in the array to check your conditions.

So first I would consolidate your ranges into a single variable since you're interested in testing a condition on the entire row:

```js
var values = mysheet1.getRange(2,2,mysheet1.getLastRow(), 4).getValues();
```

Now you loop through your 2-dimensional array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  var col1 = values[i][0]
  var col2 = values[i][2]

  if (col1 === 'ELECTRIC' && col2 === 'CONTINUE' {
    // Flash cell "H22"
    break; // Break once you find a match
  }
}
```